# XAMPP: Deamon is already running, but it's NOT apache

Tags: process, webserver, xampp

This one is giving me a headache...

I have installed `XAMPP for Linux 1.7.7` on Ubuntu 12.10. I haven't installed the latest version because of the new security "feature" which makes `XAMPP` so secure I can't get it running. But that's another story.

After it installed and ran ok for a couple of months, I now get the famous `XAMPP: Another web server daemon is already running.` error while starting XAMPP.
Now I've googled extensively and can rule out the following:

- There is no other `Apache` installation, just `XAMPP`
- There are no `apache` or `apache 2` services running
- There are no services running that use `port 80` (checked with `netstat -an grep -w 80`)

I have also done a fresh install of `xampp` 1.7.7, but that gives me the same result.
I think I have tried every solution on the first two result-pages of google and am nowhere nearer to a solution.

Can anyone give me pointers on how to find the mysterious `Webdeamon` that is already running?

---

I changed the port that XAMPP listens to in httpd.conf, which, in my case,is located in the `/opt/lampp/etc/` folder. I changed the option Listen, as that was the only option that had a value of 80. Still I get the Deamon already running-error.

The output of the `netstat` command is the following:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1189/tntnet     
tcp        0      0 192.168.178.52:35048    91.189.94.25:80         ESTABLISHED 2350/ubuntu-geoip-p
tcp        0      0 192.168.178.52:35047    91.189.94.25:80         TIME_WAIT   -
```

I have killed the `ubuntu-geoip-p` service and couldn't find a way to kill the tcp service, but I don't think the tcp service must be killed in order to start apache. Anyway, after this I still got the same error.

Any other suggestions?

---

`lsof -i :80` gave a different output and I saw that `tntnet` also used port 80. Uninstalled `tntnet` and apache started as normally. Problem solved! Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3):

Just simply run this command to terminal

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

and after that

```
/opt/lampp/lampp/ start
```

Answer (score 2):

@TedvG Update 17 Nov 2012

`ubuntu-geoip-p` was connecting to a remote IP on port 80 so it is not related.

looks like tntnet (another web server, this explains it) process was binding port 80. You have to stop it (I guess `service tntnet stop` does it, if NOT kill the `tntnet` process may be `kill -9 pid` to kill it). Also you can uninstall by complete the `tntnet` package.

Or you can change apache port, edit `lampp/etc/httpd.conf`, change the port to 8080, for example:

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 8080
```

Start it using `lampp startapache`

---

By default XAMPP's apache use port 80 (requires root for ports below 1024), anyway it can be changed by editing `$XAMPP/apache/conf/httpd.conf`

You can run

```
lsof -i :80
```

or

```
netstat -nap | grep :80
```

to figure out the process using port 80

For example if I use Python's SimpleHTTPServer module on port 8080

```
$ lsof -i :8080
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
python  16484 terry    3u  IPv4 367600      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)

$ netstat -anp | grep :8080
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16484/python
```

Very clear.

Comment: Hi Terry, thanks for this, but I'm no further. See my added comment in the original question.

Comment: Found it. See comment in original question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ha, I just updated the answer;-) In fact netstat did tell you tntnet was binding port 80 on the local host (you need to pay attention to the output format). lsof is clearler anyway. Learned something new, I didn't know tntnet LOL

Comment: @TerryWang just an aside: if you use `lsof -nPi` it gives you the numbers just like your `netstat` command.

Comment: You can use "Umit Port Scanner" to find out what is occupying the 80 Port !

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know if I'll be needing `tntnet`, and don't care for finding out the hard way, the best option seemed to change the port Apache uses.

With the latest versions of XAMPP, this is very easily done using the GUI manager included:

1. Launch the manager (use `manager-linux-x64.run` if working on 64bits):

   ```
   cd /opt/lampp
   sudo ./manager-linux.run
   ```
2. Change to the "Manage Servers" tab and select "Apache Web Server". Click on **Configure**:

   [image: XAMPP server management application]
3. Change the port on the corresponding field to, e.g., `8080` and click **OK**:

   [image: Configure Apache Web Server dialog]
4. Start all servers from the application by clicking on **Start All**.
5. Open your favourite browser and go to `http://localhost:8080`; it should redirect automatically to `http://localhost:8080/xampp`.