# xampp + apache + mysql

Tags: xampp

for my machine setup i need to run lampp and another mysql/apache instance in parallel.
I **already changed the ports** of lampp apache & mysql but it still says

```
XAMPP: Another web server daemon is already running.
XAMPP: Another MySQL daemon is already running.
```

How can i convince lampp to start mysql and apache even if there is already running an instance of them?

**EDIT:**

Well. in apache i didnt change https port. this works now. but mysql does still error about another instance.

Comment: Xampp and Lampp uses Apache + mysql, you have 2 options: 1- Install Apache and another webserver like lighttpd, and the same for mysql. The second option is have 2 instances (or more) using virtualhosts and only install one webserver/mysql server.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/217665/xampp-deamon-is-already-running-but-its-not-apache and http://askubuntu.com/questions/89156/cannot-start-xampp-on-ubuntu-11-10

Comment: Well. in apache i didnt change https port. this works now. but mysql does still error about another instance.

Comment: MySQL uses a local UNIX socket usually to listen on for connections. Did you change that as well? Please be more specific about the *exact* changes you made to the configuration.

Comment: i changed the port 3306 in my.conf.